# SSIS custom transformation component memory usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I am moving large volumes of data from Oracle to SQL server on a daily basis. The application using the oracle system stores dates in non-standard formats and these need to be converted to SQL Server dates.

I have created a custom SSIS transformation components t odo this. My issue is that when running the SSIS packages consume a huge amount of memory, often reaching multiple gigabytes. The usage keeps ballooning while the package is running.

The issue is with the process "IISServerExec.exe" running on the server. When seen from the task manager the memory usage constantly increases while running. Several of these package need to run at the same time each day, but with this memory ballooning the system can only manage two or three.

I have also followed numerous online examples and they suffer the same problem. One example is the simple component from [microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136027.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to convert a string to uppercase. This example consumed over 600mb of ram, with 6 input columns over 9 million rows.

If I create similar (but simpler) transformations using derived columns these consume less than 100mb of memory.

I am using SQL Server 2012 SP2 (11.0.5058) and have tested on four separate machines running Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2, each with all updates installed through windows update. All programming is done in VB on Visual Studio 2013. Oracle connection are using the Attunity source connector.

Is there a command you need to run at the end of the processInput section to flush out the ram or is memory usage expected?

Comment: Can you please post your SQL Server Configuration details (select * from master.sys.configurations). Then please take the list of expensive queries over the package, Check for N/W issues, Disk Perfomance, Blocking Sessions,etc What are the jobs runnings at same time your package executes. Type of database recovery model. If everything is fine how about degree of parallelism (Please don't go unless youre aware of it)?.

Comment: add an sql server tag.

Comment: The issue is with the process "IISServerExec.exe" running on the server. This is what has the ever increasing memory usage.  It occurs even when the package generates its own data and trashes it rather than write to a DB. The issue isn't with the source or destination. How will the sys.configurations help? I can provide it if needed.

Comment: I have updated my original question with more detail on the Task Manager process.